# Can I run Apache & Nginx on the same server, on the same port but bound to different IPs?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, networking, nginx

I have a dedicated server and one of the options is that I get up to 7 unique IPs if I need them. Lately I've been thinking about setting up Nginx and PHP-FPM as practice, and running my blog on it. I wouldn't want to break my existing sites, so I'm wondering if I can run them both on port 80 but bind them to different IPs, then change my blog A records to point to the second IP.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can and it probably involves less typing than your question.

In nginx:

```
listen 192.168.0.1:80;
```

In Apache:

```
Listen 192.168.0.2:80
```

Comment: Well that was easy :|